# How to change colour of textbox while typing in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Validating form input fields while typing using jQuery and my script is looks like this:

```
var firstname = /^[A-Za-z]{3,15}$/;
var day = $("#day_birthdate");
jQuery('input#firstname').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    if (firstname.test(jQuery(this).val())) {
        jQuery(this).css({
            'background': '#C2D699'
        });

    } else {
        jQuery(this).css({
            'background': '#FFC2C2'
        });

    }
});


jQuery('input#day_birthdate').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    if (day > 1) {
        jQuery(this).css({
            'background': 'green'
        });

    } else {
        jQuery(this).css({
            'background': 'red'
        });

    }
});
```

I have textbox:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.FirstName, new { id = "firstname", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "16" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Day, new { id = "day_birthdate", @class = "form-control", mask = "99", @placeholder = "dd" })
```

Main idea is to check in javascript if day is between 1 and 31 to get green colour of background while im typing it, if its not to get red colour?

Comment: A regexp which will match `1` to `31` as a _String_ is `/^([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/`

Comment: `regex` has nothing to do with `date`. it is for `firstname`

Comment: maybe an onchange listener in jquery?
Then just count .val() and change the css with .css()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of `#day_birthdate` and then `parse` the value of day to `integer`:

```
var day = parseInt($("#day_birthdate").val(), 10);
//                                    ^^^^^^
```